# "If you think that..." vs. "if you are thinking that..."

Tags: grammar, present-continuous, present-simple, stative-verbs

Is there any difference in meaning between *if you think that...* and *if you are thinking that...*? I am aware that when the verb *think* is used in the sense of having an opinion it is used in the present simple. But, in the 16th episode of the 6th season of *Friends* Joey used it in the present continuous. Here is the context:

> Rachel: Oh, I probably shouldn’t—so I will! (Joey starts making her
>   refill and Rachel notices that rain thing Joey has.) Oh! Wow! It’s
>   like it’s raining!
>
> Joey: Pretty cool, huh? But **if you’re thinking** you can put a fish in
>   there and it wouldn’t get sucked up into the mechanism, well you’d be
>   wrong.

What does he try to communicate by using *think* in the present continuous. And given the fact that Joey used in the present continuous, is possible to say the following?

> Kate **is thinking** that James is rude.

Answer (score 0):

For me, "Kate is thinking that James is rude" means that the thought of James' rudeness is currently in Kate's mind. On the other hand "Kate thinks that James is rude" means that Kate holds that opinion, even if James is not in her thoughts at that moment.

Joey's comment has the same literal meaning, but the message communicated would be identical if he had used "if you think" instead. I would put the difference in expression down to a personal style, or maybe a style of a particular sub-culture.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but how about the first part of the question?